# Solution of an improper integral

Tags: integration

Is it true the computation of the following integral when $a\in(0,1)$?

\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty n a^ndn=a\int_0^\infty na^{n-1}dn=a\frac{d}{da}\int_0^\infty a^n dn=-\frac{1}{(\log a)^2}?
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Not quite. The only suspect step is the last one. And
$$
\int_0^{\infty}a^n dn=\frac{a^n}{\ln a}\bigg\rvert_0^{\infty}=-\frac{1}{\ln a}
$$
so
$$
a\frac{d}{da}\int_0^{\infty}a^n dn=a\frac{d}{da}\left(\frac{-1}{\ln a}\right)=a\frac{1/a}{(\ln a)^2}
=\frac{1}{(\ln a)^2}.$$